# subprocess.Popen('start') fails

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Running this in python will result in a WindowsError stating it cannot find the specified file

FAILS:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('start notepad.exe')
```

In a command window, it works

```
start notepad.exe
```

Im guessing its a path thing where windows can't locate start[.exe?]  Where is this located so i can add it in the path or just include it in the Popen call.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure `start` is a program. I think it might be a built-in command of the CMD shell. Try

```
subprocess.Popen('cmd /c start notepad.exe')
```

Also, any reason why not use just:

```
subprocess.Popen('notepad.exe')
```

Comment: Also, `subprocess.Popen('start notepad.exe', shell=True)` should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
notepad = subprocess.Popen(r'start "" "C:\1.txt"', shell=True)
time.sleep(3)
print(notepad.pid)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't start Notepad. It starts the application that's set to handle txt files (which may or may not be Notepad). More importantly, it doesn't address the issue of how to invoke "start" - which was the intent of the question.